# set input checked by default not displaying

Tags: html, checkbox

I have an issue about the initialization of a checkbox. I have set it by default in the HTML file like this (with attribute `checked`) :

```
<label><input type="checkbox" value="" checked>User vs Computer</label>
```

Here's the full HTML [code](https://jsfiddle.net/x6j1ewzq/14/)

It works fine on jsfiddle (when I reload the page, non matter the checked input, I get only the first input to be checked).

But my problem is that I can't get it work in local : it does nothing when I reload the page, the checked/unchecked inputs stay the same.

Where could this error come from ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any error on console?

Comment: It's normal behavior on Firefox. If you want to refresh page completly you need to focus on page address bar and hit enter (or CTRL+SHIFT+R). 
But if you will try to refresh page normally in Google Chrome it will behave as you expect. 
If you want to fix it, just add autocomplete="off" to your form tag.

Comment: Thanks it works with autocomplete !

Comment: Which document type are you using. HTML or XHTML

Comment: I have used HTML, why ?